# How to change the appearance of list bullets in LaTeX/beamer exports?

Tags: org-export, latex, font-lock, beamer

It's very neat that simple org-mode lists get exported to `itemize` (or `enumerate`) environments in LaTeX. Yet I would like also to be able to change the face of an `\item` bullet using square brackets, as with `\item[$\Rightarrow$]`. I fail to see how this can be easily expressed in org-mode.

- `-[$\Rightarrow$]` is exported to `-[$\Rightarrow$]` (without `\item`).
- `- [$\Rightarrow$]` is exported to `\item\relax [$\Rightarrow$]`

Of course I could use `@@beamer:\item[$\Rightarrow$]@@`, but this is not really satisfying. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Plain-lists) that there are two ways to modify an `\item`:

- `- [@123]` will set the counter of enumerations (or "ordered lists") to 123.
- `- [$Rightarrow$] :: bla` will generate a "description".

Both do not really yield the flexibility that I was hoping for in my question, but it seems that this is as far as one can get.

**EDIT:**

I've stumbled over a not so obvious way to gain full flexiblity:

- `- @@latex:[$\Rightarrow$]@@` will be exported as `\item[$\Rightarrow$]`

Notice that `@@beamer:[$\Rightarrow$]@@` does not effect this.